# Is it possible to convert a public IP and port to a DNS?

Tags: dns

Must be said, I'm a complete ignorant on these matters.

Is there a way or service so I can take and IP address and its port and make it a DNS? Is it possible or am I doomed?.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'make it a DNS'? Keep in mind that questions about protocols above OSI layer 4 (like DNS) are off topic here. They can be asked on [su].

Comment: IP is a layer-3 protocol used to route packets between networks. DNS is a layer-4 protocol used to communicate datagrams between processes. UDP datagrams are encapsulated inside IP packets, so, no, you cannot convert from one to another.

Answer (score 1):

Port numbers are essentially either "well-known", which are those a server will listen on, and those allocated on the fly.  The well-known numbers are managed by IANA and published here https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

Additionally, most operating systems have a file such as Unix's `/etc/services` for this information.

"Reverse lookup" records for IP addresses are stored in the DNS as `PTR` records.  Be aware that most computers will not have any PTR records.  Most operating systems and DNS web sites have a method for looking these up.  Most Unix-like operating systems have `dig`:

```
$ dig -x 8.8.8.8
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa.   21599   IN  PTR google-public-dns-a.google.com.
[...]
```

IP addresses which don't have `PTR` records will still show the organisation they are allocated to in the WHOIS database.  The Unix tool `whois` will look these up:

```
$ whois 8.8.8.8
[...]
NetRange:       8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255
CIDR:           8.8.8.0/24
NetName:        LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8
NetHandle:      NET-8-8-8-0-1
Parent:         LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1)
NetType:        Reallocated
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Google LLC (GOGL)
RegDate:        2014-03-14
Updated:        2014-03-14
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-8-8-8-0-1
[...]
```

You will see that this address is inside a /24 allocated to Google, but nothing specifically about the host on this address.